# Не идёт поиск если искомая строка начинается с не входящих в регексп

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, exec

Здравствуйте!

Моя задача состоит в поиске 2х групп в строке:

1. +
2. последовательность # и 0

```js
var regex = /(\+?)((?:#*\s?)*(?:0*\s?)*(?:[.,])?(?:0*\s?)*(?:#*\s?)*)/;

var goodStr = '+#####0.00#######)';
var badStr = '(+#####0.00#######)';

console.log(regex.exec(goodStr));
console.log(regex.exec(badStr));
```

Проблема состоит в том, что если в строке содержится искомое значение и после него идут символы, я получаю результыты по обоим группам, но если символы перед искомой строкой, не получаю никаких результатов.

Почему такое поведение, ведь я не указываю ему поиск с начала строки?

Заметил, что такая ситуция лишь при использовании группировки.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Пустая строка подходит под твою регулярку, поэтому она и выбирается.

Поиск делается с самого левого из вхождений. Самое левое - это пустая строка в нулевой позиции - её ты и получаешь. Рекомендую как-то переделать регулярку, чтобы пустая строка не являлась корректным вариантом.

Comment: так я ему не пусту строку подаю

Comment: @ArtemS. Да, но в регулярке все можно пропустить, потому что везде либо `?` либо `*`. Получается, что первый возможный подходящий результат - `""`, пустая строка.

Comment: @qwertiy Спасибо, да действительно лучше переделать на точные вхождения